# How would you order tiles on a dashboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I am tasked with creating a dashboard interface in our ASP.NET MVC 3 web application. First I will list the features that are required for this project and then I will do my best to illustrate what I intend to create to accommodate all of these features.

### Required Features

- The dashboard will contain widgets (or tiles) that will be draggable within the dashboard interface.
- When dragging widgets, the surrounding widgets will re-order themselves appropriately.
- Widgets are not re-sizable or collapsible but they will be removable. The user will add widgets back through a menu if they desire.
- The widgets must accommodate variable width browser windows. Vertical space is pretty much unlimited.
- The widgets' heights and widths will be in increments of 300 pixels, maxing out at 900 pixels. In other words, a widget could be: 300 x 300, 600 x 300, 300 x 900, 900 x 900, and so on.

### What I plan to build

Here are a couple illustrations of what I hope to build.

[image]

The dimensions aren't perfect but this shows a dashboard with 9 widgets on it. All widgets are snug and do their best to fill the width of the screen elegantly. However, the widgets do not have to form a perfect square or rectangle. Danglers are OK as pictured below.

[image]

Note how the widths and heights of the widgets are all in increments of 300 pixels, as noted in the requirements above. This should hopefully make it easier to do the math for re-ordering the tiles. Which brings me to my problem.

### My Question

I have the concept understood but I am having trouble figuring out where to begin. I am not as proficient with math as I wish I was and I need some help getting pointed in the right direction.

How do I get from an array of widgets (of all shapes and sizes) that is sorted in no particular order, into a neatly laid out *absolutely positioned* grid of tiles that takes up space as elegantly as possible?

How do I get from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Or at least a similarly elegant layout. The tiles do not have to be in their exact places as pictured above. I just want them to play a perfect game of Tetris and fall into place without awkward gaps.

[image]

---

I need to take the width of the browser window into account and then somehow loop through the array of widgets and start adding them to some sort of virtual grid. I want it to look as elegant as I can make it.

Then, after solving how I order the widgets on the page after the initial page load I need to allow the user to move his/her widgets around and have the other widgets re-order themselves as neatly as possible to accommodate the moved widget's new position. I also need an elegant way to re-order widgets if the browser is re-sized.

I'm not expecting full-blown solutions or implementations. I just need a *push* in the right direction I think. Perhaps, a simple brain storm description of the logic for looping through the widgets and what things to calculate to arrive at the best configuration.

Comment: You want a block-filling algorithm. Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu

Comment: You are looking for some Fluid Layout plugins, Checkout [isoTope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) pluggin which does a decent job

Comment: This plugin is amazing! It does (almost) everything I want! Sadly, [this post](http://metafizzy.co/blog/mythical-drag-drop-multi-column-grid-plugin/) gives me pause :(. It doesn't work with drag and drop. That's definitely a big requirement for my project.

Comment: I am going to have to take a closer look at this. While [the isoTope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin looks pretty slick, I have a feeling I'm going to want complete control over this. An actual algorithm would give me that control I think. Thanks for the answer! I'll update with results as I continue :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure a perfect answer to this would be NP-Hard. (akin to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: Can't you just implement http://www.geckoboard.com/ or rather - why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: First, geckboard.com is not cheap. Second, I can't find any demos of it doing what I want. I signed up for their free trial and the only thing I can do is freely move the widgets on the surface. It even lets me overlap them. The widgets aren't aware of each other at all, they just snap to a grid.

Comment: Well, then I agree with Erty that you need http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html or a similar algorithm. There http://enichan.darksiren.net/wordpress/?p=49 is a quite well documented Python adaptation which you might leverage for your purpose.

Comment: Another approach using tree maps; some well documented code in the d3 group on github https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Weren't there some other answers on my question? There was one about a block filling algorithm and another about jquery.isotope. What happened to them?

Comment: It seems they were transformed into comments on my question? What in the world? I've never witnessed such dark magic. How am I supposed to accept either of them as answers now?

Comment: Why haven't you flipped that orange bar in Tetris?! Why?!! `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After investigating jQuery Masonry, jQuery isotope, and even a custom block-filling algorithm, I stumbled upon another jQuery plugin known as [jQuery Gridster](http://gridster.net/) that does exactly what I want. There are a few quirks with the plugin and it's not very polished, but with a few tweaks I was able to use it effectively.

Note: One of those quirks is the plugin's API. When you try to dynamically remove items from the grid using the remove option in the plugin API it throws a whole bunch of errors. It's some sort of race condition because it happens sporadically. The bug was probably missed because when you use the API to only remove one item at a time it works 99% of the time. If you remove more than one item in rapid succession (either by looping through and calling the API multiple times, or by passing the remove function a wrapped set with more than one element) then you'll get a bunch of console errors.

I had a need to remove all tiles from the grid and reload a new set of tiles. It was easier to just use jQuery to remove the element Gridster was invoked on and then call the plugin fresh from the beginning, passing it the new set of tiles.

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com). It seems like it can at least solve some of the problems that you're looking to tackle. Also, for some inspiration and some code to look through, check out how StackExchange lists their QA sites: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid